# Resizing panels within a wx.SplitterWindow

Tags: wxpython

I have a wx.Grid and another wx.Panel that are to the left and right of a wx.SplitterWindow.

The grid starts out a certain height, but its height can grow as rows are added or expanded. Right now when this happens, the grid's scroll bars appears. I would much rather the grid expand in height. The splitter window itself doesn't need to change in height, because the right-hand panel is already much taller than the grid.

Is there a way to use a vertical sizer within a horizontally split SplitterWindow?

Or is there another clean way to update a grid's size to take up all of the available vertical space within the SplitterWindow?

I tried:

1. Putting the grid within a panel which itself has a sizer. This didn't work.
2. After the rows were added, within the Grid I called self.SetSize(self.GetBestSize()). This didn't work.

Comment: This probably needs a concrete example